# Storage Access Framwork and creation of a file with uneditable filename

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

Is it possible to use Storage Access Framwork with ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT and make the file name sticky - not possible for the user to change?

This code, from the documentation, creates a new window so that the user can choose the location for the new file, but also the possibility to change filename. The latter is unwanted...

```
private void createFile(String mimeType, String fileName) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);

    // Filter to only show results that can be "opened", such as
    // a file (as opposed to a list of contacts or timezones).
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    // Create a file with the requested MIME type.
    intent.setType(mimeType);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, fileName);
    startActivityForResult(intent, WRITE_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

I've searched for an answer to this, but has not been able to find any. Is the only approach to rename the file after it has been saved?

Comment: You better let the user only choose a directory where the file should be written.

Comment: Yepp. That's what I want, but the question is how to do this using Storage Access Framework. When using SAF API with ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT, it returns an URI to the newly created file. And the name of the file can be edited in the SAF GUI. Cant find out how to turn off this ability to edit the filename...

Comment: Choose a directory with saf instead of creating a file with saf. ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.

Answer (score 0):

no. Take a look at the source for [com.android.documentsui.SaveFragement](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/96c620595bd0585f934b0971b4552c57845e9a78/packages/DocumentsUI/src/com/android/documentsui/SaveFragment.java). There is a textwatcher that does not enforce anything to which we have access, and there is method setSaveEnabled() called from [com.android.documentsui.DocumentActivity.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/96c620595bd0585f934b0971b4552c57845e9a78/packages/DocumentsUI/src/com/android/documentsui/DocumentsActivity.java) based only to enforce the write directory's permissions, but nothing to enforce file naming conventions.